# What does Gmail mean by the yellow arrows for priority?

Tags: gmail

My priority mail has three kinds of yellow arrows:

```
1. >>
2. >
3. blank with a yellow marker.
```

What do that mean and can I increase/reduce the arrow count?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. `>>`  ------ Messages sent only to you
2. `>`   -------- Messages sent to your address (not a mailing list)
3. blank---- Messages sent to a mailing list inclusive of your address

The addition of the yellow arrow is the new important and unread feature. So for example the third will be for important messages by mailing lists. Whereas just a yellow border represents an important read message.

- You can of course change which is important via [filters](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=186541).
- Also you can [remove](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=186535) the yellow arrows.
- To remove the `>>` and `>` go to your settings and turn off personal level indicators.

As far as I am aware these are the only ways to modify the arrows. It is not possible to change the number of arrows.